# Passing Large String as arguments - unoptimized?

Tags: javascript, string

I am receiving some very large strings as a response of Ajax request which are used to generate views on the front end.

I know if its an object then a reference to the object is passed as a argument. But what's the case with String? Is it bad for optimization to pass very large string as arguments?

```
fetchData(empId, date1, date2).done(function(response) {
      //here response is a very large string
      ...
      ..
      createView(response);
      refreshCumulatives(response);
      ...
      ..
  }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {

  });
```

Comment: it doesn't matter. In terms of performance, it depends on what you're planning to do with that string ?

Answer (score 0):

> I know if its a object then a reference to the object is passed as a
>   argument. But what's the case with String?

Even string will be passed as argument to that `callback` function in `done`. It's just data which you're passing to the callback function, it doesn't matter whether it's string or object.

What you're going to do with that `response` in your `done` callback will make the actual difference in terms of performance.

Answer (score 0):

[Everything is an object in JS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects), including [Strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String). Passing a string argument is no different as passing any other argument (i.e. approaching a 32 or 64-bit pointer).